# How can I create and send a text file through XmlHttpRequest or $.ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

The server is expecting an html or txt file from a form with name: "websitetopdf". The file is created dynamically on client javascript and only have to work on Chrome.

This is the form that should be sending it:

```
<form action="send.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="websitetopdf" id="websitetopdf">
<input name="localfile" type="file" id="localfile" size="58">
<input name="filetype" type="hidden" id="filetype" value="IMG">
<input name="source" type="hidden" id="source" value="SOFT">
<input name="converternow" type="submit" id="converternow" style="width: 130px; font-weight: bold;" value="Convert to Image">
</form>
```

I want to directly send the file to send.php, I have tried this:

```
$("#sender").on("click", function(e) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "http://.../send.php", true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) console.log(xhr.responseText);
    };
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        if (xhr.status == 200) console.log("uploaded"); //(correctly uploaded)
        else console.log("Error " + e.status + " occurred uploading your file.<br \/>");
    };
    var blob = new Blob(['abc123'], {type: 'text/plain'});

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("localfile", blob);
    formData.append("filetype", "IMG");
    formData.append("source", "SOFT");
    xhr.send(formData);
});
```

I always get "**it's not a valid file**" from server

Comment: don't override the content type, for uploading files it does matter.

Comment: I removed it, still no luck.

Comment: oh, duh, use POST; didn't notice that the first time... your server also might want an extension on the filename you create with FormData...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It started working when I added a filename for the blob in the FormData object:

```
formData.append("localfile", blob, "filename.txt");
```

Comment: If this worked, then there is an issue with your server code.  The 3rd (name) parameter on `FormData`'s `append` method is not supported in all browsers.  You should not rely on it.

Comment: ok thank you I didnt't know that, I'm only using it within a Chrome app so it's ok for now. I guess that's needed to recognize the file format before returning it (html or txt to jpg)

Comment: You should be identifying the file server side using magic byte matching, instead of file extension matching.

Comment: The server side script is not mine, it's an external web service.